# Distributed Spring Sessions. Order of sequence in multiple service instances

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm moving my sessions out of the process in my spring boot application to avoid session stickiness. In my current application, I only allow one session per user because my session state is changed by each user request.

Now my question is when I have distributed sessions what will be the order of sequence of steps. For eg., if a user sends requests in order `1,2,3,4` and I've 2 service instances A and B, `A` will get `1,3` and `B` will get `2,4`.

What I want is them to execute requests in sequence `1,2,3,4` and one after another so that my distributed session reflects the changes made by previous requests. I know I can limit the number of sessions in distributed spring sessions but will that guarantee the order of execution in different instances?

Comment: Why don't you move token based authentication for distributed system ?

Comment: We don't have any authentication in our service. Just sessions to recognize it's the same user.

Comment: If you have distributed session and your user request dispatch to different server, then I guess its not possible to maintain request order (I could be wrong). You should move sticky session (that one you said earlier). You can do it in your load-balancer lavel(e.g ha-proxy).

Comment: We already have that, and we are trying to move away from it because it does not scale well.